# How to display products on the home page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Installed the WooCommerce plugin. I need to display products on the main page. How can i do this? I need to display all products in 3 columns on the main page. I have added a shortcode:

```js
<?php echo do_shortcode("[products columns='3']"); ?>
```

But the products are displayed in one column. I know that it is possible to make the main page a directory. But can it be done differently?

[image]

has class "columns-3" but they stay in one column

Comment: check if you loaded the woo styles. check the html structure.

Comment: Yes, styles are loaded. On the store page, products in 3 columns. And on the main one only

Comment: give url atleast we dont have magic ball